# Engage with widget on IE by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't really tried working on this before, so I have no idea what I am doing at the moment. I have limited knowledge of html so not sure whether I am doing right. Basically what I aim to do is opening the Internet explorer by macro, changing some elements based id and click submit button on the website to show the data. Then I need keep working on the next step.

As you can see from the code I was trying to engage with the widget on IE by id number from html codes.

```
Sub Automate_IE_Enter_Data()
'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object

    Dim objbutton As Object


    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "http://cfpsg1/plant/Reports/ScrapReport.aspx"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertantly skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'Webpage Loaded
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

    IE.Document.getelementbyid("1stGroupBy").Value = "3"

    'Find &amp; Fill Out Input Box

    IE.Document.getelementbyid("PageContent_uxStartDate").Value = "06/21/2019"
    IE.Document.getelementbyid("PageContent_uxEndDate").Value = "06/21/2019"

    Set objbutton = IE.Document.getelementbyid("PageContent_btnQuery")
    objbutton.Focus
    objbutton.Click


    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: html]

First thing first the `webpage` popped up but nothing changed of widgets besides an

> error message "method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser 2' failed"

show on `IE.Document.getelementbyid("1stGroupBy").Value = "3"` row.

Comment: Is this a local url as it doesn't load for me. It would help to include the relevant html by using the snippet tool via [edit]

Comment: @QHarr Please see edited post

Comment: @QHarr it's not the first time I got this 'document' error but seems like .document is a property within IE? So that really confuses me...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to interact with a dropdown so you want syntax such as

```
IE.Document.querySelector("[value='3']").Selected = True
```

You could also use

```
IE.Document.querySelector("#1stGroupBy").SelectedIndex = 2   'change to appropriate index
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed that part but it gives the same error as I described.

Answer (score 0):

Error `"method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser 2' failed"` may be due to Integrity level

You can try below mentioned code by changing `Integrity` level as Medium

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://cfpsg1/plant/Reports/ScrapReport.aspx"
IE.Navigate URL

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

and try other line of codes to avoid this issue also please refer [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/)

Please add ref Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library based on your req

Comment: Thanks. That did eliminate the error, but a new one comes up "automation error unspecified error" on the same row.

Comment: Try this `Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")`  or you can refer the link provided in answer you can understand why this error triggers

Comment: Tried this method but still automation error unspecified error.

Comment: Close all other IE instance and try execute the code also make sure references are added in project

Comment: I have added internet control in reference at  the beginning. The error kept popping up until just now I changed "Do while" to "Do until" and there is no error... I understand readystate = 4 means "the results is on the way back" status. Am I doing the right thing? And what does this loop actually mean?

Comment: This loop actually continues to execute until web page processing gets completes , it will not allow next line to execute until web page gets loaded. Is your problem gets fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I realize that will not be the answer so I changed it back and now the error comes up again.

Comment: or try this  `Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IS.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://cfpsg1/plant/Reports/ScrapReport.aspx"`